# Sum across multiple sheets with varying cell locations

Tags: excel, vba

Pretty new to VBA. I've been trying to automate a template that my office uses quite frequently, right now the template is just a bunch of coloured cells with copy pasted formulas that constantly get messed up as people try to adjust the size of it themselves. So far I've managed to set it up so that they just enter how many stations they need for the project (which determines how many rows they'll need). Then they press create and the code I've got set up fully creates the table for them. Usually we need more than one table for each project, so I have 5 sheets loaded into the template so it's ready to go for anyone to use as not everyone would be able to assign the macro's if I only gave them one and they were to copy paste the sheets.

So now I need to have the first page provide a total of each material from every sheet's table (stripping, road cut, etc). The main reason I'm struggling with this is because the cells that need to be summed could be in any row depending on how many stations they set up in each table.

Any help on this would be great, also please don't judge my coding too harshly since I've only got about 8 hours total trying to teach myself how to use it as coding isn't something I went to school for or is in my job description...just trying to help the office out with a side project! :)

```
Sub Test()
    
    Dim x As Integer
    x = Range("Y3").Value
    
    Range("c8:e8").Copy Range("C9:E" & (x + 8 - 2))
    Range("g8:i8").Copy Range("g9:i" & (x + 8 - 2))
    Range("k8:m8").Copy Range("k9:m" & (x + 8 - 2))
    Range("o8:q8").Copy Range("o9:q" & (x + 8 - 2))
    Range("s8:u8").Copy Range("s9:u" & (x + 8 - 2))
    
    Range("C" & (x + 8 - 1), "E" & (x + 8 - 1)).Value = "-"
    Range("g" & (x + 8 - 1), "i" & (x + 8 - 1)).Value = "-"
    Range("k" & (x + 8 - 1), "m" & (x + 8 - 1)).Value = "-"
    Range("o" & (x + 8 - 1), "q" & (x + 8 - 1)).Value = "-"
    Range("s" & (x + 8 - 1), "u" & (x + 8 - 1)).Value = "-"
    
    Range("B" & (x + 8), "D" & (x + 8)).Value = "sum row"
    Range("F" & (x + 8), "H" & (x + 8)).Value = "sum row"
    Range("J" & (x + 8), "L" & (x + 8)).Value = "sum row"
    Range("N" & (x + 8), "P" & (x + 8)).Value = "sum row"
    Range("R" & (x + 8), "T" & (x + 8)).Value = "sum row"
    
    'lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
        
    Range("E" & (x + 8)).Value = "=SUM(E8:E" & (x + 6) & ")"
    Range("I" & (x + 8)).Value = "=SUM(I8:I" & (x + 6) & ")"
    Range("M" & (x + 8)).Value = "=SUM(M8:M" & (x + 6) & ")"
    Range("Q" & (x + 8)).Value = "=SUM(Q8:Q" & (x + 6) & ")"
    Range("U" & (x + 8)).Value = "=SUM(U8:U" & (x + 6) & ")"
    
    Range("E" & (x + 9)).Value = "Border"
    Range("I" & (x + 9)).Value = "Border"
    Range("M" & (x + 9)).Value = "Border"
    Range("Q" & (x + 9)).Value = "Border"
    Range("U" & (x + 9)).Value = "Border"
       
    Range("A" & (x + 8)).Value = "TOTALS"
    
End Sub
```

Sorry for the super low quality GIF, hopefully it helps show what I've done at a basic level at least.

[image]

Comment: If you're trying to put formulas in a cell, use `cell.formula = "=sum...`

Comment: If you're looking for which column specific data is in, you can use `Rows(1).find("Something").address` or `Rows(1).find("Something").column`